# Swift Extension to Observable with Generic Type Constraint

Tags: swift, generics, observable, where-clause, rx-swift

I'm trying to add an extension to Observable.
The code looks like this:

```
extension Observable where Element == ApiResponse<ItemsContainer<T>>, T:Codable
```

I'm receiving the following exception: `Use of undeclared type T`.

So apparently this doesn't work.
The only thing missing is to constrain the generic inside `ItemsContainer` to conform to `Codable`.
Could be as simple as a syntactical issue or maybe I'm just not good enough with generics. Any help is appreciated!

**Edit**: To give the idea - ApiResponse and ItemsContainer look like this

```
public struct ApiResponse<ApiModel> {  
  public let data: ApiModel?  
}  

struct ItemsContainer<Items>: Codable  where Items: Codable {  
   let items: [Items]
}
```

Comment: I *think* you need to make a protocol that represents an ApiResponse, but without more context, I'm not sure enough to actually post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Issue

You cannot constraint extensions to a **Model Type** which holds generic values, without specifying the **Model Type** of the generic value.

You only constrain protocols based on their `associatedtype`s or generics based on their generic type, on the extension signature. Therefore `T` is not recognized, because none of the protocols or generic declare it.

[image: Ray Wenderlich Scheme]

### Solution

So by keeping in mind what I said above, a **Model Type** needs to be fully defined on the extension context. **But wait that does not satisfy our requirement, we want it to be generic!**

> Then we do not need a **Model Type**, we need a **protocol**!

We have two Model Types (**ApiResponse** and **ItemsContainer**) which we need to know the generic type, therefore we need two protocols for each of them.

#### ApiResponse

Let's create one named `ApiResponseProtocol`

```
public protocol ApiResponseProtocol {
    associatedtype Model
    var data: Model? { get }
}
```

Cool, the `associatedtype Model` will play our role as the generic value for the `ApiModel` on the object. Let's make `ApiResponse` conform to `ApiResponseProtocol`

```
public struct ApiResponse<ApiModel>: ApiResponseProtocol {
    public let data: ApiModel?
}
```

Generic `ApiModel` here can be defined as `Model` from the protocol.

#### ItemsContainer

Next steps would be the same for the `ItemsContainer`

```
public protocol ItemsContainerProtocol {
    associatedtype Item
    var items: [Item] { get }
}

public struct ItemsContainer<Items>: Codable, ItemsContainerProtocol where Items: Codable {
    public let items: [Items]
}
```

#### Extension

Now since we can access each of the generic types from the protocol (`associatedtypes`), the output would become something like this:

```
// This would be for example ApiResponse<ItemsContainer<Model>> where Model is a Model Type conforming to Codable
extension Observable where Element: ApiResponseProtocol, Element.Model: ItemsContainerProtocol, Element.Model.Item: Codable {}
```